# Whitelisting Api-Gateway to access ALB using WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, amazon-waf

I'm having an `Application Load Balancer` and an `API Gateway`. I'm trying to enforce the flow in such a way that only the requests from API-Gateway is allowed to access my loadbalancer. Is there some way I could use AWS WAF to get it done?

Comment: I don't think so. From what I see a recommended way is to use [NLB + ALB combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715115/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-access-to-an-application-load-balancer).

Comment: Alternatively, you could enforce requests coming from API Gateway on the targets of your ALB by using client-side certificates. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Answer (score 2):

API gateway supports so called [Private Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) which use `VpcLink` resource and NLB. With them you can:

> expose your HTTP/HTTPS resources behind an Amazon VPC for access by clients outside of the VPC.

The docs also provide a tutorial how to use them: 
[Build an API with API Gateway Private Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html)

Comment: I can't use NLB, NLB can't handle paths at the moment.  Using an NLB+ ALB Combo is expensive.